# AngularJS translate is not working in placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

I am using clip-two which is developed in AngularJS in which I am using translate multi-language using JSON file it is working for all HTML tags but I when trying to translate placeholder using this it not working.

JSON format

```
"addemployee": {
  "Name": "Name",
  "Typename": "Type name",
  "Employeid": "Employe id",
  "Username": "Username",
  "Contactno": "Contact no.",
  "Typecontactno": "Type contact no.",
  "Password": "Password",
  "Typepassword":"Type password",
  "Confirmpassword": "Confirm password",
  "Selectimagefile": "Select an image file",
  "remove": "Remove",
  "cancel": "Cancel",
  "upload": "Upload",
  "Addemployee": "Add employee",
  "TypeConfirmpassword": "Type Confirm password"
}
```

Works for HTML tag

```
<h1 class="mainTitle" translate="addemployee.Addemployee"> Add Employee</h1>
```

But doesn't not work in input placeholder

```
placeholder=""
```

Comment: Yeah, can't see how `placeholder=""` is going to do much of anything

Answer (score 0):

You did try just like this ?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'addemployee.Addemployee' | translate }}" ng-model="myModel">
```

**Edit:**

```
<input type="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'addemployee.Addemployee' | translate }}" name="firstName" ng-model="employee.name" id="name" class="form-control" required>

"addemployee": { 
    "Name": "Name", 
    "Typename": "Type name", 
    "Employeid": "Employe id", 
    "Username": "Username", 
    "Contactno": "Contact no.", 
    "Typecontactno": "Type contact no.", 
    "Password": "Password", 
    "Typepassword":"Type password", 
    "Confirmpassword": "Confirm password", 
    "Selectimagefile": "Select an image file", 
    "remove": "Remove", 
    "cancel": "Cancel", 
    "upload": "Upload", 
    "Addemployee": "Add employee", 
    "TypeConfirmpassword": "Type Confirm password" 
}
```

You have to use condition for two translation just like `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

Comment: This will surely resolved your problem. https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/874

Comment: i am translating it in English and hebrew language

Comment: Hi it is working for english has problem with hebrew

Comment: i used in html ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'addemployee.Addemployee' | translate }}"

Comment: <input type="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'addemployee.Addemployee' | translate }}" name="firstName" ng-model="employee.name" id="name" class="form-control" required>

Comment: "addemployee": {
        "Name": "Name",
        "Typename": "Type name",
        "Employeid": "Employe id",
        "Username": "Username",
        "Contactno": "Contact no.",
        "Typecontactno": "Type contact no.",
        "Password": "Password",
        "Typepassword":"Type password",
        "Confirmpassword": "Confirm password",
        "Selectimagefile": "Select an image file",
        "remove": "Remove",
        "cancel": "Cancel",
        "upload": "Upload",
        "Addemployee": "Add employee",
        "TypeConfirmpassword": "Type Confirm password"
    }

Comment: facing same issue with data-toltip="delete" i want to traslate it also

Comment: do like this data-toltip="{{delete | translate}}" and Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: I used   uib-tooltip="{{customerlist.Edit | translate}}" not working

Comment: uib-tooltip="{{ 'customerlist.Edit' | translate}}" make sure you written just like this.

Comment: It is working for English but don't work  for Hebrew in Hebrew its look like

&;#1458&;#1506&;#1463&;#1500&; same for placeholder